# How could I discover whether a domain is registered from the client?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dns, client-side

I'd like to present the users of a Web app with a form where they type in a prospective domain name, and then using JavaScript the client looks up whether it's available.

Is there a way to do that without involving my own host machine? Like sending an AJAX request from the user's browser to some Web service that looks up domains? Does such a service exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few domain lookup API services out there (e.g., http://www.dynadot.com/domain/api2.html), although I don't know any that support callbacks. I haven't read much of the documentation, either.

From the surface, it looks like you'd have to make the request server-side (using PHP or whatever you use) and return the results back to the user (AJAX most likely). It's not completely client-side (e.g., JSONP), but it should be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use ajaxwhois service. This is a complete ajax based call. You can use .ajax function of jQuery for the same.

To automatically launch a domain search, use this url: http://ajaxwhois.com/?domainname or http://ajaxwhois.com/?domainname.extension

Reference:- [ajaxwhois](http://ajaxwhois.com/help)

Comment: That's a great idea but it isn't clear how my JS code would discover whether the domain is available. That info is generated after the ajaxwhois.com page loads, so it isn't part of the returned HTML. So I wouldn't be able to grep for "is available" as far as I can tell. (Am I missing something?) I think the reason they provide that service is that they want people to actually visit their site and register domains through their godaddy affiliate links.

Comment: peeping into page source code will give you some idea. Yes it indeed invokes a godaddy url (form action URL). You can use the same thing in your front end JS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://lbolla.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/get-registered-domain-in-python-and-javascript/

I've implemented reg-dom-libs (http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/) in Javascript and Python.